# Continue chain after reduce in lodash

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I want to do something like as follows

```
_(data)
  .map(() => /** ... */)
  .reduce(function (modifier, doc) {
    modifier.$set = modifier.$set || {};
    modifier.$set.names = doc.names;
    return modifier;
  }, {})
  .map(() => /** ... */)
  .flatten()
```

However, it appears that after reduce, the chain breaks.

Is there a way to continue the chain from the value returned by reduce?

Comment: so what does the `reduce` return? No way for us to reproduce your issue. A demo that replicates it would help

Comment: something that looks like `{ $set: { names: [ 'alex', 'jeff' ] } }`

Comment: yeah, that's just an example though. I mean I want to continue with the chain as this object

Comment: start a new chain, reduce returns it own non-array thing, which can't be chained...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`reduce()` method is not guaranteed to produce a collection (array, object, or string) upon which other methods could operate, therefore it makes no sense that it could be chainable by default.

From lodash documentation on lodash object (`_`):

> Methods that operate on and return arrays, collections, and functions
>   can be chained together. Methods that retrieve a single value or may
>   return a primitive value will automatically end the chain returning
>   the unwrapped value.

[_ documentation](http://devdocs.io/lodash/index#_)

You can however explicitly enforce chaining by using `_.chain()`. This would allow for single values and primitives to be explicitly returned within lodash wrapper for continued chaining.

So for your code that might look like:

```
_.chain(data)
  .map(() => /** ... */)
  .reduce(function (modifier, doc) {
    modifier.$set = modifier.$set || {};
    modifier.$set.names = doc.names;
    return modifier;
  }, {})
  .map(() => /** ... */)
  .flatten()
```

[_.chain() documentation](http://devdocs.io/lodash/index#chain)

Comment: Ah okay that makes sense why they don't allow it to be chainable then

Comment: @corvid I updated my answer with some information on `_.chain()` which may help your use case.

Comment: I accepted the answer, I didn't know implicit and explicit chaining were different

Answer (score 2):

The lodash docs say that reduce() is not chainable. See here:
"The wrapper methods that are not chainable by default are: ... reduce"
https://lodash.com/docs#_